# Video with transparent background file-size issue

Tags: file-formats, export

A client asked me to do an animated product visualization in 3D and then render out the animation in 4K with a transparent background to put on their website. The animation is done but if I want to export it without background I realized that Quicktime is the only option. The 4-sec video then becomes 1,8GB in size! Is there any way around this or do I have to tell them that we can't go with 4K? or can I compress it or use some other format? The animation is also choppy in the video exported without background. When I render out an MP4 with the background it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transparent video on the web is possible, but it's going to only work for users with modern browsers.  You'll need to export in two different codecs - one for Chrome users, one for Safari.

From [this site](https://www.rotato.app/read/transparent-videos-for-the-web):

> Safari supports HEVC with alpha, Chrome does not.
> Chrome supports VP9 with alpha, Safari does not.

You need to export an HEVC with alpha channel for Safari.

You need a .webm VP9 codec with alpha for Chrome.

The animation codec you've exported at is not designed for web publishing.  It's a lossless very large codec designed for editing or archiving your finished project before you use it to make a smaller lossy version to go on the web.

This is how to make the webm using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "movie-prores.mov" -c:v libvpx-vp9 movie-webm.webm
```

I would recommend also exporting a "fallback version" for browsers that can't cope with transparent video (as a normal h264 mp4 or webm).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will try this!

Comment: You’re welcome- please mark it as an answer if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a good option, depending on the animation, is a CSS or JavaScript animation of a PNG sequence. This works well for 360° animations.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=360+javascript+animation

Comment: Yes - this is a solution a lot of newspapers use for their "scrollytelling" animations.  Works better for shorter diagramatic animations than photographic work due to file sizes.